# NSOperation - queuePriority

Tags: ios, nsoperation

What does queuepriority mean. According to what i understand, it decides the execution within the operation queue. But, when i use a queue with only 1 concurrent operation, the queue priority does not make any effect. It executes the operation in the same order in which it is added.

Answer (score 1):

The `queuePriority` property might have no effect, as you said yourself, in cases where a queue is serial only in which case operations are executed in the order they arrive. This is not 100% accurate because the operations will attempt to be launched in the order of priorities but I'm guessing that in the case you describe the operations are getting enqueued slower than they are being executed. Consider this example of a completely legal execution sequence:

[image]

If Op1 already executes by the time Op2 is enqueued, Op1 will not be interrupted in favor of Op2, even if Op2's priority is higher.

Comment: I think that there is a rough "promise" that operations will be executed by these priorities when the OS sees it fit. When there are concurrent operations this is easier to perform. Also note the threadPriority property which helps explicitly define the priority of the queue an operation will be executed in once it's launched.

Comment: If there are more than one concurrent operations in an operation queue then only priority make sense.

Comment: Am adding all to the queue but setting the setmaxconcurrentoperation to 1.